# Paginação em pesquisa falha ao alternar paginas

Tags: php

Ao incrementar um sistema de paginação em meu sistema de busca, recebo um erro ao passar da primeira pagina para outra..

> Erro:

http://localhost/admin/paginas/pesquisa.php?busca=orixa?pag=2?pag=3

> Formulário HTML:

```
<form class="pesquisa" action="http://<?php echo $url; ?>/admin/paginas/pesquisa.php" method="GET">
    <input type="search" name="busca" class="input-busca" placeholder="Faça uma pesquisa.."  required>
</form>
```

> SCRIPT PAGINAÇÃO:

```
<?php
    $url          = $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'];  // imprime:www.site.com.br
    if(isset($_GET['pag'])){     
    $tamanhoGET = 0 - strlen($_GET['pag']);     
    $urlEndereco = substr($_SERVER ['REQUEST_URI'], 0, $tamanhoGET);    
    }else{
    $urlEndereco = $_SERVER ['REQUEST_URI'].'?pag=';
    } 
    ?>
    <div class="paginacao">
    <?php
    if($pag!=1){
        echo "<a href='http://".$url.$urlEndereco.($pag-1)."'> Anterior</a>"; 
    }
    if($contador<=$maximo){
        echo "<td>Existe apenas uma única página</td>";
    } else{
        for($i=1;$i<=$paginas;$i++){
            if($pag==$i){
                echo "<a class='link-ativo' href='http://".$url.$urlEndereco.$i."'> ".$i."</a>";
            }else{
                echo "<a href='http://".$url.$urlEndereco.$i."'> ".$i."</a>";
            }
        }
    }
    if($pag!=$paginas){
        echo "<a href='http://".$url.$urlEndereco.($pag+1)."'> Próxima</a>";
    }
    ?>
    </div>
```

> SCRIPT DE PESQUISA

```
<?php
include('../../config.php'); 
//if(empty($busca)) {
//    header('Location: ../');
//}    
    $busca = $_GET['busca'];

include('../header.php'); 

$sql_res=mysqli_query($conexao,"SELECT * FROM conteudo WHERE MATCH (titulo, texto, autor, id_categoria, id_pontos, id_orixas) AGAINST ('$busca') ORDER BY id DESC");
$contador=mysqli_num_rows($sql_res);
//Verificando se já selecionada alguma página
if(empty($_GET['pag'])){
    $pag=1;
}else{
    $pag = "$_GET[pag]";} //Pegando página selecionada na URL
if($pag >= '1'){
        $pag = $pag;
}else{
    $pag = '1';
}
$maximo=2; //Quantidade Máxima de posts por página
$inicio = ($pag * $maximo) - $maximo; //Variável para LIMIT da sql
$paginas=ceil($contador/$maximo);   //Quantidade de páginas 

$sql = "SELECT * FROM conteudo WHERE MATCH (titulo, texto, autor, id_categoria, id_pontos, id_orixas) AGAINST ('$busca') ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT $inicio, $maximo";
$exe = mysqli_query($conexao, $sql);
$contaRegistros = mysqli_num_rows($exe);
?>
```

Ao realizar uma busca, a URL fica da seguinte forma:

```
http://localhost/admin/paginas/pesquisa.php?busca=teste
```

E ao passar de página:

```
http://localhost/admin/paginas/pesquisa.php?busca=teste?pag=2?pag=3
```

Porém, os resultados sempre são os mesmos.

Obs: Como disse, o sistema de paginação funciona perfeitamente nos outros arquivos, exceto na pesquisa..
O link está ficando da forma citada acima por conta de:

```
echo "<a href='http://".$url.$urlEndereco.$i."'> ".$i."</a>";
```

Aonde $url -> $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']; 
e $urlEndereco -> `$urlEndereco = $_SERVER ['REQUEST_URI'].'?pag=';`

Comment: Thiago editei novamente: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/111534/3635

Answer (score 2):

`$_POST` é para formulários com `<form method="POST">`, para usar páginação provavelmente você terá que usar GET, supondo que a url seja assim:

```
 pagina.php?busca=1
```

Em todas variaveis GET ou POST sempre verifique os valores por exemplo:

```
$busca = '';
if (false === empty($_GET['busca']) && is_numeric($_GET['busca'])) {
    $busca = $_GET['busca'];
}
```

O `empty` verifica se a variável existe e se ela é vazia.

Olhando o código que você me enviou notei que você tentou recriar a url, mas nestas questões de paginação com querystring você pode omitir a url, desta maneira por exemplo:

```
<a href="?buscador=...&amp;pag=1">1</a>
```

O form deve ficar assim:

```
<form class="pesquisa" action="pesquisa.php" method="GET">
    <input type="search" name="busca" class="input-busca" placeholder="Faça uma pesquisa.."  required>
</form>
```

> Nota: `type=search` talvez não seja suportado por todos navegadores.

A paginação deve ficar assim:

```
<div class="paginacao">
<?php
$busca = '';
if (false === empty($_GET['busca']) && is_numeric($_GET['busca'])) {
    $busca = htmlspecialchars($_GET['busca']);
}

$buscaQueryString = '?buscador=' . $busca . '&amp;pag=';//Gera a querystring da páginação

if($pag != 1){
    echo '<a href="', $buscaQueryString, $pag - 1,'">Anterior</a>'; 
}
if($contador<=$maximo){
    echo "<td>Existe apenas uma única página</td>";
} else{
    for($i=1;$i<=$paginas;$i++){
        if($pag==$i){
            echo '<a class="link-ativo" href="', $buscaQueryString, $i,'">', $i, '</a>';
        } else {
            echo '<a href="', $buscaQueryString, $i,'">', $i, '</a>';
        }
    }
}
if($pag != $paginas){
    echo '<a href="', $buscaQueryString, $pag + 1,'">Anterior</a>'; 
}
?>
</div>
```

E o outro arquivo assim:

```
<?php
include('../../config.php');

$busca = '';
if (false === empty($_GET['busca']) && is_numeric($_GET['busca'])) {
    $busca = htmlspecialchars($_GET['busca']);
}

include('../header.php');

$sql_res=mysqli_query($conexao,"SELECT * FROM conteudo WHERE MATCH (titulo, texto, autor, id_categoria, id_pontos, id_orixas) AGAINST ('$busca') ORDER BY id DESC");
$contador=mysqli_num_rows($sql_res);
//Verificando se já selecionada alguma página
if(empty($_GET['pag'])) {
    $pag=1;
}else{
    $pag = $_GET['pag'];
} //Pegando página selecionada na URL

if($pag >= 1){
        $pag = $pag;
}else{
    $pag = '1';
}
$maximo=2; //Quantidade Máxima de posts por página
$inicio = ($pag * $maximo) - $maximo; //Variável para LIMIT da sql
$paginas=ceil($contador/$maximo);   //Quantidade de páginas 

$sql = "SELECT * FROM conteudo WHERE MATCH (titulo, texto, autor, id_categoria, id_pontos, id_orixas) AGAINST ('$busca') ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT $inicio, $maximo";
$exe = mysqli_query($conexao, $sql);
$contaRegistros = mysqli_num_rows($exe);
?>
```

Note que o `echo` pode trabalhar com virgula ao invés de pontos e eu inverti os apóstrofos com as aspas pois para o html talvez seja melhor usar aspas.

Leia a documentação:

- http://php.net/manual/en/function.echo.php
- http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php

Comment: Fiz as devidas alterações, e ao passar de página a URL fica: http://localhost/admin/paginas/pesquisa.php?busca=teste?pag=2
Porém, ao passar novamente, a URL fica: http://localhost/admin/paginas/pesquisa.php?busca=orixa?pag=2?pag=3

Isso por que o sistema de busca está criando a url da seguinte forma: echo "<a href='http://".$url.$urlEndereco.$i."'> ".$i."</a>";
$url é $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']; e $urlEndereco é $urlEndereco = $_SERVER ['REQUEST_URI'].'?pag=';

Comment: Desculpe-me pelo comentario, irei postar o codigo completo.

Comment: Postei o código completo. A paginação funciona perfeitamente. Porém, quando eu a utilizo na pesquisa, os links ficam dessa forma que citei.

Comment: Acho que eu esqueci de mencionar que o script de paginação é um arquivo a parte, que é incluso apenas em arquivos que eu uso paginação.. o script de busca é do arquivo pesquisa.php

Comment: O link ficou: http://localhost/admin/paginas/pesquisa.php?busca=&pag=2
Acredito que seja algo nessa linha: $buscaQueryString = '?busca=' . $busca . '&amp;pag=';//Gera a querystring da páginação

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/35246/discussion-between-thiago-barros-and-guilherme-nascimento).

Answer (score 0):

Está colocando o campo de buscas em um form?
Tente:

```
<form method="POST" action="buscar.php">
<input type="text" name="busca" placeholder="Digite aqui...">
<input type="submit" value="Buscar">
</form>
```

E no arquivo buscar, apenas deve ter:

```
<?php
$busca = $_POST['busca']; 

seu código aqui

?>
```

Se mostrar sue código, será mais fácil.